# How can i implement extension for single sign-on for ios 13

Tags: single-sign-on, ios13

I show the video of extensible SSO for ios 13 in this link
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/301

But i am not able to find proper way to implement redirect/credential type of SSO extension for ios 13.

Comment: Same problem for me.

Comment: Hey Hi @SamiulIslamSami & KhyatiBhensdadia did you able to build any solution on Extensible SSO iOS13?

Comment: Hi @SamiulIslamSami & KhyatiBhensdadia did you able to build any solution for SSO extension iOS13??